# How to proceed if I want to rename a file in an existing Git repo?

Tags: git, github

Should I use the `git mv oldfilename newfilename` command? or just `mv oldfilename newfilename` without prefixing it with `git`?

Comment: Either is fine.

Comment: If you do not notify git about it, git will start reporting a file as deleted (as a pending to be committed change). It will be the same thing (in terms of it being ok) if you ask git to remove the file and add it after you moved it _manually_ (`git rm old-name; git add new-name`)... if there are no changes in the file past a certain threshold, git considers it to be a movement _automagically_.

Comment: So what's the problem? There is no specific command or command sequence that you need to do. Use git-mv(1) or mv(1) + git-add(1)—doesn't matter.